# Smalltalk user defined subclass issue.

Tags: object, subclass, smalltalk, subclassing, gnu-smalltalk

I have created a class named animal and I want to create two subclasses of that class I just created lynx and rabbit. However when ever I try to compile the program I get the following error on the line where I define my first subclass of animal, lynx:

```
Object: #lynx error: did not understand #lynx
MessageNotUnderstood(Exception)>>signal (ExcHandling.st:254)
Symbol(Object)>>doesNotUnderstand: #lynx (SysExcept.st:1407)
UndefinedObject>>executeStatements (newanimal.st:121)
Object: nil error: did not understand #comment:
MessageNotUnderstood(Exception)>>signal (ExcHandling.st:254)
UndefinedObject(Object)>>doesNotUnderstand: #comment: (SysExcept.st:1407)
UndefinedObject>>executeStatements (newanimal.st:123)
newanimal.st:125: key lynx not found
newanimal.st:125: expected Eval, Namespace or class     definition
newanimal.st:134: expected Eval, Namespace or class definition
newanimal.st:137: expected expression
```

I define the lynx subclass right after I have defined animal which is a subclass of object. Here is my code for both classes.

```
Object subclass: #animal .
animal instanceVariableNames: ' animals '.
animal class instanceVariableNames: ' id type '.
animal comment: 'I am the class for all animals' .

animal class extend [
    create: type [
        (animals := nil) ifTrue: [ self init ].
        (type == 'rabbit') ifTrue: [animals := rabbit new] .
        (type == 'lynx') ifTrue: [animals := lynx new] .
        ^ animals .
    ]
    getid ["returns the animals unique id"
        | tempAnimal temp |
        tempAnimal := grid asArray at: 'id' .
        "temp :=  ."
    ]
    getrow: id ["returns the animals grid row"
        | tempAnimal temp |
        grid do: [:each | 
            tempAnimal := grid at: each .
            (tempAnimal at: id == id) ifTrue: [temp:= tempAnimal at: 'row'. ^ temp ] . ]

    ]
    getcol: id ["returns the animals grid col"
        | tempAnimal temp |
        grid do: [:each | 
            tempAnimal := grid at: each .
            (tempAnimal at: id == id) ifTrue: [temp:= tempAnimal at: 'col'. ^ temp ] . ]

    ]
    getdirection: id ["returns the animals movement direction"
        | tempAnimal temp |
        grid do: [:each | 
            tempAnimal := grid at: each .
            (tempAnimal at: id == id) ifTrue: [temp:= tempAnimal at: 'direction'. ^ temp ] . ]
    ]
    setdirection ["sets animals movement direction"
        | direction |
        direction := grid rand .
        ^ direction .
    ]
]
animal extend [
    init [
        animals := Dictionary new.
    ]
]

#animal subclass: #lynx
lynx instanceVariableNames: ' direction '.
lynx class instanceVariableNames: ' lynxdictionary '. 
lynx comment: 'I am the subclass of animal that is lynxs' .

lynx class extend [
    new [
        lynxdictionary := Dictionary new .
        lynxdictionary add: 'type' -> 'lynx' .
        direction := animal setdirection .
        lynxdictionary add: 'direction' -> direction .
        lynxdictionary := grid placerow:lynxdictionary .
        ^ lynxdictionary .
    ]
    act [
        | row col tempAniaml |
    ]
]
```

Comment: Please write class names capitalised, this is a convention and it makes code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Uko's comment:

The compiler can probably not tell that `animal` is a class because the name is not capitalized. Instead, the compiler thinks it's a variable name. That variable looks to be uninitialized and is therefore `nil`. That's why you're getting a `MessageNotUnderstood` exception for the message send `#lynx`.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a period:

```
#animal subclass: #lynx. "<---- added period here"
lynx instanceVariableNames: ' direction '.
```

Your previous code:

```
#animal subclass: #lynx
lynx instanceVariableNames: ' direction '.
```

could be rewritten as:

```
#animal subclass: #lynx lynx instanceVariableNames: ' direction '.
```

Hence the error stating that the Symbol #lynx did not understand the #lynx message